# Usage of std::list::sort hangs my program

Tags: c++, stdlist

I have a program in C++ that organizes a bunch of college courses I want to take.  It does so by taking input from the console (with things like course code, description, etc.), organizing each course by major, then outputting it all to a nicely-formatted, easy-to-read HTML file.  Later, I plan on thinning out the list with a lot of research.

I implement each course as an object, which is added to a list when I finish entering the info.  When I'm finished with all the info, `list::sort` should sort each course by major and code (eg, CSE 380 comes after CSE 110, and both come before ECO 108).  The formatting afterwards is easy.

To sort, I have to implement a simple function, because even though not doing so is technically valid, I get a weird-ass error, I guess due to no '<' operator for my Course class.  My function looks like this;

```
bool courseCompare(Course course1, Course course2) { return course1.getCode() < course2.getCode(); }
```

Where the `getCode()` returns a small string that holds the course code in three-letter/digit format (like "AMS 401").  This is meant to facilitate alphabetical order, obviously.

I call the sort method like so;

`all_the_courses.sort(courseCompare);`

Where `all_the_courses` is a list.

However, whenever I used std::list, the program just stops.  Doesn't crash, gives no output, just sits there not responding when I input anything and hit Enter.  Any ideas?

Comment: Wait, are you use C++ for scripting? Consider using a different programming language.

Comment: I'd guess that your comparator does not implement a _Strict Weak Ordering_. What happens when you break into the process and examine it in your debugger?

Comment: @Tomalak: `course1.getCode() < course2.getCode();` looks pretty strictly weak to me...

Comment: @Xeo: `int Course::getCode() { return std::rand(); }`

Comment: @Tomalak: That's described directly beneath that - returns a string. Oh wait, I see what you mean. ` @arrogantc: Does `getCode()` return a `std::string`?

Comment: @Tomalak: "Where the getCode() returns a small string that holds the course code in three-letter/digit format (like "AMS 401")."

Comment: @Xeo: BTW if you insert a sly backtick (\`) into your comment, you can direct at multiple people and thereby include @arrogantc too :D

Comment: @Xeo: Prove to me that that course code upholds SWO. No, wait, let's get the OP to do that.

Comment: @Xeo: FYI http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/155739 point 7. It's completely ridiculous. (Worth noting that until just now I didn't realise the second target wouldn't be notified... so the whole thing is kind of moot now. Bah.)

Comment: nightcracker: I should have, in retrospect, but I'm too far in to make such a switch.  Tomalak: I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it seems like I was going about this the completely wrong way.  Turns out my problem is something completely different (involving filestreams).  I need to figure out what it is, but it's NOT the sorting; a simple `cout` (which I really should have used before) reveals that.  Sorry, everyone!

Comment: Note to all: If at first you don't succeed, see if the Boost libraries have.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the parameters to your comparison function by value, not reference, so it's possible that the error lies in your copy constructor. The usual way to write a comparison function is with const references which avoids copying the object altogether:

```
bool courseCompare(const Course &course1, const Course &course2)
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to help.  I just get this; /home/jesse/Desktop/Code Projects/C++/Stony Brook Course Organizer/Stony Brook Course Organizer/main.cpp|11|error: no matching function for call to ‘Course::getCode() const’|  Isn't '<' already defined for strings?

Comment: to get past the compiler error related to 'const', remove the 'const' as 'bool courseCompare(Course &course1, Course &course2)' definition

Comment: @arrogantc, the problem isn't in `<`, it's in `getCode` which should be declared as a `const` function since it doesn't modify the object. All accessors should be declared as `const` functions by putting `const` directly after the function parameter closing parenthesis.

Comment: That gets it compiling, but still doesn't fix my list issue.  Still got the same hanging.  What could I be doing improperly?  Might it be how I set up my class?

Comment: @arrogantc, the only thing remaining is to ensure that `getCode` always returns the same string from the same object.

Comment: I assure you that it does, with the way the `code` member is defined it doesn't change.  What might be causing this to hang?  An open filestream, perhaps?